# Asynchronous generator and array promise

Tags: javascript

This my code

```
async function* promisGenerator(arrPromise) {}  //???

const promisList = [
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(15), 200)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(17), 600)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(42), 500))
];

(async () => {
  const asyncGenerator = promisGenerator(promisList);
  for await (let value of asyncGenerator) {
    console.log(value); // 17, 42, 15,
  }
})();
```

i have array promise. I have to write an asynchronous generator `promisGenerator`,which we will return the value in descending order `17, 42, 15`.please help write a generator `promisGenerator`.

Comment: Your Promises are currently all resolving immediately, at the same time. Is that intended, or a typo?

Comment: The times here are all different `200 , 600, 500` ?.no prints.

Comment: Yes, but you're still calling `resolve` immediately in each, so each Promise in the array resolves immediately. You probably need to promisify the `setTimeout`s properly.

Comment: An async generator doesn't make much sense here, because it wouldn't yield anything until all promises are fulfilled, which kind of defeats the whole point.  You can just use `Promise.all` on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want the array of Promises to resolve in the order of the second parameter passed to `setTimeout`, you need to promisify them properly. (Don't call `resolve` immediately - rather, just *pass* `resolve` to `setTimeout`.) Then, chain a `.then` onto each Promise which pushes the resolve value to an array. Await a `Promise.all` on the array of Promises, and then you can reverse the array of values and `yield` each of them:

```js
async function* promisGenerator(arrPromise) {
  const resolvedValues = [];
  arrPromise.forEach(prom => prom.then(value => resolvedValues.push(value)));
  await Promise.all(arrPromise);
  resolvedValues.reverse();
  for (const value of resolvedValues) {
    yield value;
  }
}

const promisList = [
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200, 15)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 600, 17)),
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 42))
];

(async() => {
  const asyncGenerator = promisGenerator(promisList);
  for await (let value of asyncGenerator) {
    console.log(value); // 17, 42, 15,
  }
})();
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work like that?  `const resolvedValues = await Promise.all([...arrPromise]);`

Comment: Because you want the resolved values in reverse error of their resolution - just doing `await Promise.all` will give you the resolved values in the order they were in the passed array.